# Why am I getting this behavior?

Tags: support, bug, status-bydesign

[image]

I just logged into my account today and saw this sort of a notification if I can call it. It first showed the 4 items for review. I reviewed one of them and then the rest disappeared, I thought that someone else also may have reviewed other which were pending. But this `4` doesn't go. Why is that so?

Comment: I have the same issue; the number is not very accurate and/or useful in my experience. I believe it also counts duplicates e.g. a question can be in *First Post* and *Late Answers* and you will see *2*. As soon as you review it, it will be removed from both queues.

Comment: In my experience, on other Stacks, that is the number of items in the Suggested Edits queue and is refreshed only on a full page browser request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Caching. That number is expensive to calculate so it is heavily cached. It will update sooner or later.

It is also *not* customized per user and shows the total number of reviews in the system, including ones that may be no longer available to you.